# EBJ 3 MDB annotations for the attributes of EBJ 2.1 MDB

Tags: migration, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6

We are migration EJB from 2.1 to 3.1 on JBoss EAP 6.4.5 with Java EE 6.

So am trying to use the annotations for the attributes of the `ejb-jar.xml` and `jboss.xml` files. Please check below the attributes which i cant find annotations representations in EJB 3.1.

1. `<configuration-name>`
2. `<activation-config-property-name>MaxPoolSize</activation-config-property-name>`
3. I have a enviornment variable attribute  which has value as xml file. Is this also possible to annotate in EJB bean.?

   ```
       <env-entry>
               <env-entry-name>ejb/abcd</env-entry-name>
               <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
               <env-entry-value>config/xyz.xml</env-entry-value>
       </env-entry>
   ```
4. Is is possible to annotate this as well?

   ```
   <container-configurations>
    <container-configuration extends="some webmethods message">
       <container-name>Singleton Webmethods Queue Message Inflow Driven Bean</container-name>
       <!-- Override the MDB Pool Size -->
       <container-pool-conf>
         <MinimumSize>1</MinimumSize>
         <MaximumSize>8</MaximumSize>
         <strictMaximumSize>true</strictMaximumSize>
       </container-pool-conf>
    </container-configuration>
   </container-configurations>
   ```

Comment: For `env-entry`, the equivalent would be `@Resource String abcd = "config/xyz.xml"`.  I don't know about the others.

Comment: Thanks Brett, can i use the @Resource at class level for above env-entry?

Comment: Almost: you can, but there is no way to specify `<env-entry-value>` using annotations, so you have to rely on default field initialization.

Comment: Cool... In ejb2.1 we didn't have any instance variable for <env-entry> in the ejb bean, that means it was loaded to context on class level. The solution you referring @Resource String abcd = "config/xyz.xml", will this work out ?

Comment: I don't know if it will work for you or not.  You would need to put that default value in each location that needed to look it up.  Alternatively, you could just leave the XML in place; there's no real reason you need to stop using XML.  As another alternative, you could create a singleton session bean, put the field there, and then look up the singleton and call a method.  That will ensure all callers see a consistent default value.

Comment: oh oh!...At any cost we wanted to eliminate the ejb-jar.xml and jboss.xml files. Thanks for alternative option, but that will be again like write a whole new file and doing lookup from ejbbean. can you please answer this .  I have class declared in abc.xml using spring(IOC) and added abc.xml into xyz.xml (cofiguration file) an added xyz.xml in <env-entry> in ejb-jar.xml where spring beans are instantiated on ejb instance loading. So if i add @Resource String abcd = "config/xyz.xml"  inside ejbbean, will my spring class be instantiated? i hope am not making you confuse.Thanks in advance Brett..

Comment: I don't know anything about Spring, sorry.

Comment: ok.Np. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS provides a jboss-ejb3.xml that allows you to perform configuration that is not defined in the spec. It is possible to reference an MDB Pool with this file where the pool is defined in standalone-full.xml or it's equivalent.

You can read more about it here : [jboss-ejb3.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/jboss-ejb3.xml+Reference)

Read the section describing the Pool Namespace.